Use file name from ansible files like variable
everyone. I'm newbie in ansible.
I need deploy various files to various folder in PCs via ansible.
I have files like:
foo.txt
bar.txt

And a need copy this files into PCs folder like:
/home/foo/file
/home/bar/file

How can i check is file exist and copy, if didn't
I tried use ansible.builtin.copy, but i don't know, how use file name as variable.

"check if file exist and copy, if didn't", because of Desired state and ‘idempotency’ there is no need to check before, just copy. The module will do the rest. "i don't know, how use file name as variable.", the documentation Using variables has examples like Referencing simple variables.

You will want to use ansible.windows.win_copy for Windows computers.

For example, given the files on the controller
shell> ls /tmp/ansible/files/
admin.txt  bob.txt  www.txt

Get the files
  files: "{{ query('fileglob', '/tmp/ansible/files/*') }}"

gives
  files:
  - /tmp/ansible/files/admin.txt
  - /tmp/ansible/files/www.txt
  - /tmp/ansible/files/bob.txt

Get the names
  names: "{{ files | map('basename') | map('splitext') | map('first') }}"

gives
  names:
  - admin
  - www
  - bob

and create the dictionary below
  names_files: "{{ dict(names | zip(files)) }}"

gives
  names_files:
    admin: /tmp/ansible/files/admin.txt
    bob: /tmp/ansible/files/bob.txt
    www: /tmp/ansible/files/www.txt

Find the directories on the remote hosts
    - find:
        paths: /home
        file_type: directory
      register: out

and declare the list of the directories
dirs: "{{ out.files | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') }}"

gives, for example, on three remote hosts
ok: [test_01] => 
  dirs:
  - admin
  - theo
  - bob
ok: [test_02] => 
  dirs:
  - admin
ok: [test_03] => 
  dirs:
  - admin

Copy the files if the directories exist
    - copy:
        src: "{{ item.value }}"
        dest: "/home/{{ item.key }}/file"
      loop: "{{ names_files | dict2items }}"
      when: item.key in dirs

gives with --check --diff options
changed: [test_01] => (item={'key': 'admin', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/admin.txt'})
changed: [test_02] => (item={'key': 'admin', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/admin.txt'})
changed: [test_03] => (item={'key': 'admin', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/admin.txt'})
skipping: [test_01] => (item={'key': 'www', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/www.txt'}) 
skipping: [test_03] => (item={'key': 'www', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/www.txt'}) 
skipping: [test_02] => (item={'key': 'www', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/www.txt'}) 
skipping: [test_03] => (item={'key': 'bob', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/bob.txt'}) 
skipping: [test_02] => (item={'key': 'bob', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/bob.txt'}) 
changed: [test_01] => (item={'key': 'bob', 'value': '/tmp/ansible/files/bob.txt'})



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  vars:

    files: "{{ query('fileglob', '/tmp/ansible/files/*') }}"
    names: "{{ files | map('basename') | map('splitext') | map('first') }}"
    names_files: "{{ dict(names | zip(files)) }}"
    dirs: "{{ out.files | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: files
        - debug:
            var: names
        - debug:
            var: names_files
      run_once: true

    - find:
        paths: /home
        file_type: directory
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: dirs

    - copy:
        src: "{{ item.value }}"
        dest: "/home/{{ item.key }}/file"
      loop: "{{ names_files | dict2items }}"
      when: item.key in dirs



Thank you, Vladimir.
I'm not sure about ansible version, but i change some vars  and it's works.
